# Identifying first character of a word in a string

Tags: java

I want to identify if my index is at a word boundary or not.

E.g. In the string `"National Aeronautics Space Research is an amazing organization"`.

I want to check if my index is at `R` of `research`. I could use a `charAt(index)` but I want to make this generic as this will be part of a larger algorithm to identify acronym longforms. So essentially I want to identify word boundaries.

Help for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if index is greater than 0, you could just check for index-1 value ?. Also, what do you mean by - *So essentially I want to identify word boundaries.*?. Can you explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I have not got your second part of your question,"but I want to make this generic....,

```
public class IndexVal {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            String goodText="National Aeronautics Space Research is an amazing organization";
            String[] parts = goodText.split(" ");
            for (String part : parts) {
               System.out.println("Index is at a word boundary " +part.charAt(0)+" ");

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to get indexes of word boundaries. Then this code may be what you need. It uses regular expressions

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\w");
    String s = "National Aeronautics Space Research is an amazing organization";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.start());
    }
```